# Problem with render animation in Blender 2.8 : black screen

Tags: rendering

Hello all Blender users and fans.
I am currentyl using Blender for adding animation to video editing. With Blender 2.8 I have got problem to render animation.
In the main view I have added a background picture (Add -> Image -> Background) and after a more little picture which is a simple circle (Add -> Image -> Background). I have animated this picture with keyframes to move from left to right as you can see on this picture of my screen :

[image]

When I wanted to make a render on the animation as a video first Blender when suddenly crashing. It was because of the render engine which was checked on Eevee by default :

[image]

After I have changed the render engine to Workbench or Cycles Blender doesn't crash when I render the video but this video is now rendered as a black screen ! I have changed the parameters of Workbench and the video render has changed from a black screen to a grey screen but of course my animation is not rendered.

And now I don't know what to do. I had never this problem of black screen or crash with Blender 2.79. That's why I suppose this is a problem with parameters of the Render Engine. If somebody could help me or a at least recommend me a way to find a solution I would be very very grateful.

[image]

Comment: check the compositor, is everything connected to the compositor input?